# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode')

Tags: javascript, html

I have added the following script to my web page where a newsletter sign up action can occur. I am trying to display some custom content once the user subscribes.

```
<script>
  function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

    var news = document.getElementsByClassName("et_pb_newsletter_success")[0].selectedIndex;
    var text = document.createTextNode("Thank you for joining our SOS Family! We are very grateful to have you with us. Thanks to compassionate people like you, SOS is meeting needs and improving the lives of our friends and neighbours in District 69. You can expect valuable emails from us on a regular basis, and you can unsubscribe at any time.");
    var learn = document.createTextNode("Learn more about SOS.")
  insertAfter(news,text);
  insertAfter(text,learn);
  
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://sosd69.com/wp-content/uploads/newsletter_success.jpeg";
    
  insertAfter(learn,img);

    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Watch Video";
    btn.onclick = function () {
        window.location='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcYyhazCiHs';
    };
    btn.classList.add("et_pb_button_0");
  insertAfter(img,btn);
</script>
```

I am receiving the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode')
    at insertAfter ((index):666)
    at (index):672
```

Is there an error in the way I have created the insertAfter function? Perhaps the issue is that the script is loading before the "et_pb_newsletter_success" class is created, when the subscribe button is clicked. Any insight would be much apppreciated!

Comment: Apart from the `gEBCN` issue which the answerers have handled below, there's a logical error, newly-created textnodes are not inserted to any element yet, hence they can't have a parent node.

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about appending newly created texnodes to the elements in the et_pb_newsletter_success class in this case?

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName - gives an array, so you need to get the items from that array and use it.

```
var news = document.getElementsByClassName("et_pb_newsletter_success")[0];
```

Comment: Sorry! It looks like the code I posted wasn't updated, but I do have that line indexing the HTML array. The error is still happening regardless. I've edited the question to show the updated code.

Comment: What is this selectedIndex? it doesn't have such property that why its failing. Put a debugger and check what values are you passing to insertAfter(). I guess it wil lwork if you remove ".selectedIndex"

Comment: Removing .selectedIndex results in: ```Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://sosd69.com/contact-sos/:670:10)
    at e (https://sosd69.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:30038)
    at t (https://sosd69.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:30340) ```

Comment: Try adding your code to codepen/jsfiddle/etc and post it in your question. Then it would be easy for us to help you.